# Weird animation when deleting row if I declare an @EnvironmentObject var

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-list

Everything works fine until I declare `@EnvironmentObject private var VM: VModel`, even if I don't actually use the VM var.

If I delete a row by swiping, for a second the row remains, just without the background color. In the image, you can see how the first row (La Massana) looks like for a second before disappearing.

[image]

The code is the following (I deleted some unnecessary code):

```
@main
struct VoyageXApp: App {
    
    @StateObject private var model = VModel()
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .environmentObject(model)
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {

    var body: some View {
        #if os(iOS)
        TabBar()
        #else
        Sidebar()
        #endif
    }
}


struct CountryDetailUIView: View {

    @EnvironmentObject private var VM: VModel //THIS IS WHAT CAUSES THE PROBLEM
    @State var isShowingAddRView = false
    @Binding var country: Country
    
    //@StateObject var VM = VModel()
    
    let titleName: String
    let titleDMode:NavigationBarItem.TitleDisplayMode
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            List {
                if Bundle.main.url(forResource: country.name, withExtension: "svg") != nil {
                
                    CountryDetailRow(country: $country)

                    DetailMapView(svgName: country.name, regions: country.regions!.compactMap{$0.visited ? $0.name : nil})

                    CounterRow(title: "REGVISITATE", nVisited: country.regions!.filter{$0.visited}.count, tot: country.regionsNames.count)

                    ForEach(country.regions!.filter{$0.visited}, id: \.self) { region in
                        
                        CountryRow(name: region.name, flagName: (country.name + "-" + region.name), flagCountryName: country.name, isVisited: true, isNew: false)

                    }.onDelete(perform: delete)
                } else {
                    Text("NONDISP")
                }

            }
            }
        }
    }
    
    func delete(at offsets: IndexSet) {
        
        for i in offsets.makeIterator() {

            if let i = country.regions!.firstIndex(where: { $0.id == country.regions!.filter{$0.visited}[i].id }) {
                
                country.regions![i].visited = false
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and see: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example (MRE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). I suspect your issue is that you are supplying the `. environmentObject()` with a `@StateObject`. Try `private let model = VModel()`. I can't test this without the MRE.

Comment: @Yrb but if I do that, doesn't this defeat the purpose of sharing data between the views of the TabBar?

Comment: If you are passing it as an `EnvironmentObject` you can use `let` and it will work as an `ObservableObject`. This question is why you should be posting the MRE. We don't actually know what you intend to do with the `EnvironmentObject`, and that can always change a response.

Comment: Regardless, even with 'private let model = VModel()' the bug persists. I switched to another solution, using '@Binding' instead and it now works fine. Thank you anyway !